# Why ConcurrencyException occur when I changed added entity state as modified

Tags: c#, concurrency, entity-framework-core

I have entity as following

```
public class Application
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OfficeName { get; set; }
    public Person Persons { get; set; }
}

 public class Person
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name{ get; set; }
     public List<PersonContact> Contacts{ get; set; }
 }

 public class PersonContact
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string ContactName { get; set; }
 }

 public void InsertApplication(Application app)
 {
    _applicationDbSet.Add(app);
    _personDbSet.AddOrUpdate(app.Person);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges(); //exception occur here
 }
```

I try to insert `Application` to DB. After add application to `DBSet` I check if person exsit in DB by name I changed state of person entry. When I look `ChangeTraker` everything seen well. `Application` is added. `Person` is modified and `PersonContact` is added. When I call `SaveChanged` I get error as following

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'Database
>   operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 104
>   row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were
>   loaded.

Why dose this exception occur? Can someone explain why if it is normal

Comment: What queries did EF run while saving the data? (Trace log)

Answer (score 0):

If database is MS Sql server you can launch a trace with the SQL profile to debug sql request.

Your classes do not seem to have a declared primary key

```
public class Application
{
     [Key] //key attribut
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OfficeName { get; set; }
    public Person Persons { get; set; }
}

 public class Person
 {
     [Key] //key attribut
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name{ get; set; }
     public List<PersonContact> Contacts{ get; set; }
 }

 public class PersonContact
 {
     [Key] //key attribut
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string ContactName { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: I am sorry but  I use fluent api.  I mean that I set all ids as primary key

Comment: EFCore seem to save automatically related data https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/saving/related-data

Comment: Try without adding related people